# How to select the type of an object from an array typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, typescript-typings

I have a generated type like this : (I can't manipulate it)

```
type Users = Array<
| {
  typename: "personal";
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
| {
  typename: "socialMedia";
  userName: string;
  email: string;
}
>;
```

Now i want to write a new type that refers to Users > typename socialMedia

```
{
  typename: "socialMedia";
  userName: string;
  email: string;
}
```

I want the new type to be the code above

```
type userSocialMediaInfo = ?????
```

is this possible?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  You want a type that corresponds to an element with `typename: "socialMedial"`  What is wrong with the type you have given as an example?  Does it not work for some reason?

Comment: @MattMorgan I want the new type to refer to the original type and I don't want to manually write the new type because the original type may change in the future and I don't want to change it again every time the original type changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with the [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) built-in type. First, you want to "unwrap" the array into the union. That's possible by indexing into it with `number`:

```
Users[number]
```

I'm using `number` in case the type could be at tuple. After we get the union, we can then use `Extract`. Here is what `Extract` does:

> Constructs a type by extracting from `Type` all union members that are assignable to `Union`.

That should mean if we use:

```
Extract<Users[number], { typename: "socialMedia" }>
```

we'll get only the members of the union that have a type name of "socialMedia", since those are the only members that are assignable to `{ typename: "socialMedia" }`.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WzPALN)

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to construct the `Users` type from two different types, this way you have access to the types without deriving, [for  example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=43&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOwIYBsoF4oG8AoKKUSDAWwgC4oAiSJNLOgbmKgDMBLJYAOXRVaiYPG6oA5uxKZ0owcKijxU9gF92hMtADKyAMbcsAWQgATY7gIcdlGvRRHTF42w4BXRAkUOVE6Q4ICnRuTBExAI0tHSgAVW8kawBBeHh0EAAeOCYMTAAfKH1nTDNLdAA%20diA):

```
type Personal = {
  typename: "personal";
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
};

type SocialMedia = {
  typename: "socialMedia";
  userName: string;
  email: string;
};

type Users = Array<Personal| SocialMedia>;
```

Otherwise if you can't control the `Users` type, you can access its underlying variants by indexing it with `number`, and then intersecting the type with the relevant discriminator ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATnKBeKBBRiCGIA8AUAD5QDehUUokAdjgLYQBcUARJMgPb0A2bAbkpQAZgEtkwAHKMWUOMERjaAcyFVeOBTKasFS1UIC%20JcsJoR6u9nC4BjMTl4BZCABNHg4QFcEiHXL6ymrCEAw4Yrx6isHGhAB8QoQWUL5IAMr2ji7ujgCStCJcaLB%20cADatN4MAEZIALpQAGTkVBZWcmy2Dk6uHjiCRgJAA)):

```
type Users = Array<
| {
  typename: "personal";
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
| {
  typename: "socialMedia";
  userName: string;
  email: string;
}
>;

type userSocialMediaInfo = Users[number] & {  typename: "socialMedia";};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

`type UserSocialMediaInfo = Extract<Users[0], { typename: "socialMedia" }>`

**Explanation**

`Users[0]` - Take the first type from array.

`Extract<...>` - Extract type from union which is assignable to `{ typename: "socialMedia" }`.

**Better alternative**

It would be more correct to adjust type generation logic to generate types separately.

```
type PersonelInfo = {
    typename: "personal";
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

type SocialMediaInfo = {
    typename: "socialMedia";
    userName: string;
    email: string;
}

type Users = Array<PersonelInfo | SocialMediaInfo>;
```

Comment: `Users[number]` would be better in case the type is a tuple.

Comment: In this particular case it is a multi type array and there is no any difference between `T[0]` and `T[number]`.

Comment: *In case* the type changes and it's a tuple. I'm just being safe. There is no difference anyways, so might as well use the one that doesn't need changing if the type changes, right :)